# How can I make a connection through a ForeignKey prefetch_related?

Tags: python, django

I need to optimize my table. In template in each row displays information about the graphic and creates each time a query. If I have a lot of lines, it takes a very long time.

My model:

```
class Graphic(models.Model):
    text = CharField(...)
    comment = CharField(...)
    profile = ForeignKey(Profile)


class CardiogramData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(...)
    cardiogram = models.ForeignKey('common.Graphic', related_name='data_set')
```

If the connection was from the class of graphic, then everything would be easy.

In view:

```
...
    queryset = Graphic.objects.prefetch_related('profile', 'data_set')
```

'data_set' does not work, but 'profile' works as needed.

Comment: Are your migrations up to date?

Comment: @pythad, everything is updated, I was convinced

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
queryset = Graphic.objects.select_related('profile').prefetch_related('data_set')
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It did not help me. 'profile' working as it should and 'data_set' - no.